# Kotlin script eval and Java 11 with inline function in the DSL

Tags: kotlin, java-11, jsr223

Our project decided to make the "jump" and move to open implementations, and grabbing the opportunity to move the Kotlin Java compatibility to version 11.

It introduced several 3rd-party library compatibility challenges, but I was able to solve them all.

Now I use Kotlin 1.3.50 (with the new JSR223 engine) with Java 11 target and builds and runs correctly.

```
plugins {
   kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation(kotlin("scripting-jsr223-embeddable"))
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}
```

The application uses complex DSL scripts in the form of kts. They worked perfectly prior upgrading to 11, but fails to evaluate since switching to version 11.

When the code calls the eval:

```
    val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!
    val building = engine.eval(src) as Building
```

it throws class version incompatibility exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot inline bytecode built 
   with JVM target 11 into bytecode that is being built with 
   JVM target 1.8. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option
...
```

From this error, I can't determine whether the script engine compiles the script into Java 8 class and then tries to add the result to the core code; or the script tries to use a class which is not in Java 11 format.

How can fix this incompatibility or how could I debug all the project (including 3rd party) classes of their class file version?

Note: The DSL is too complex to give a clear and simple example, however I was able to eval the script of "2+2" without problem.

**EDIT 1: A simplified example**

After a long lets-comment-out session, I was able to locate the problem: it fails when I use a reified inline function in the script. This discovery made it possible to create a simple example:

```
package hu.app

import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

/**
 * A class representing a type-value pair
 */
class TypedProperty<T : Any>(val type: KClass<T>, initialValue: T? = null) {
    var value: T? = initialValue

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Any> create(initialValue: T? = null) = TypedProperty(T::class, initialValue)
    }

}

/**
 * The root object the DSL creates. Body omitted for simplicity.
 */
class Building {
    // Class body is omitted for simplicity
}


/**
 * The simple DSL
 */
@DslMarker
annotation class MyDsl

@MyDsl
class PropertyBuilder constructor() {
    @MyDsl
    val properties: Map<String, TypedProperty<*>> = mutableMapOf()

    /**
     * An extension function for String allowing the creation of a freely typed, but typed properties.
     * This function causes the problem!
     */
    @MyDsl
    inline infix fun <reified T : Any> String.set(value: T?) {
        val p = (properties as MutableMap).getOrPut(this, { TypedProperty.create(value) })
        if (T::class == p.type)
            (p as TypedProperty<T>).apply { this.value = value }
        else
            throw RuntimeException("Property '$this' is reassigned with different type. Original: ${p.type.simpleName}, new: ${T::class.simpleName}")
    }

}

// Root of the DSL
@MyDsl
fun building(id: String = "Unnamed", op: BuildingBuilder.() -> Unit) = BuildingBuilder(id).apply(op).build()

// An interface for DSL classes with property support
@MyDsl
interface HasPropertiesBuilder {
    @MyDsl
    val properties: PropertyBuilder

    @MyDsl
    fun properties(op: PropertyBuilder.() -> Unit) = properties.op()
}

// The builder of the root object: it has properties
class BuildingBuilder(val id: String) : HasPropertiesBuilder {
    override val properties = PropertyBuilder()

    // This function body is omitted for simplification
    fun build() : Building = Building()
}


fun main() {
    // Initialize the engine (new 1.3.50 engine is used)
    val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")!!

    // Evaluation
    val res = engine.eval("""
        import hu.pmi.autoparking.app.*

        building {

            properties {
               "X" set 42
            }
        }
    """.trimIndent()) as Building
}
```

In the above example, there is an extension function on String letting to create typed properties. It has **reified** type parameter, so it should be inline. This method cause the exception: if the `"X" set 42` line is removed, the script compiles.

Digging deeper, now it is clear, that the script engine compiles into Java 8 and therefor, when it tries to inject the inline function which is in Java 11 class format, it fails.

So the new question: how could I tell the JSR223 kotlin engine to compile to version 11?